# in_array not working explode

Tags: php

[image]

I am not able to figure out why my condition is not working while the ip address is in the array. Why condition is failing as shown in image

```
<?php $valid_ip_list = explode(',',$this->valid_ips);
           echo $client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
           print('<pre>');
           print_r($valid_ip_list);
            if(in_array($client_ip ,$valid_ip_list))
                {
                    echo 'I am here';
                }
           else
                {
                    echo 'Condition fail';
                }
?>
```

Problem solved with the help of `array_map('trim', explode(',', $valid_ips))`

Comment: Check for white space characters in the ip list values... use var_dump() rather than echo and print_r to get more information

Comment: what does `strlen($this->valid_ips[2])` give you? Or better, change `print_r` to `var_dump` and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help

```
$valid_ips = '192.100.100.61,192.100.100.2,127.0.0.1';

// authorized
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array_map("trim", explode(',', $valid_ips)))) {
    //... 
}

// unauthorized
else {
    //...
}
```

Comment: ips will be dynamic every time so i can not give static

Comment: is there any way to trim every element of array in explode

Comment: How does re-arranging the code help? It is still essentially the same.